# Converting C to CPP with Function Pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting, function-pointers

In my C code, I have the following lines:

```
void* (*functionSteps[numSteps])();
functionSteps[0] = (void*) filterEvenFoos;
functionSteps[1] = (void*) timesFooByTwo,
functionSteps[2] = (void*) mapFooToBar;
```

Which works fine. I have an array of functions that return a void* type and take any number of inputs.

I tried to do the same in C++ and I'm getting the error

`assigning to 'void *(*)()' from incompatible type 'void *'`

Is this not possible in CPP?

Comment: What are the declarations of these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this not possible in CPP?

Strictly speaking, no, due to type safety and other rules governing function prototypes. However, depending on your needs, that C code can be ported to C++.

Firstly, it should be noted that the function signature of `void* fn();` in C is not the same in C++. In C++ to get the same function signature, you need to introduce [variadic arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) like so: `void* fn(...);`, however, it should be noted that you cannot access the variadic arguments portably for a function signature like this.

In C++, `void* fn();` is the same as `void* fn(void);` in C. To this, if your functions had variable inputs in C, you would need to do a little extra work in C++ using the variadic argument list.

For example, if your code were something similar to the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_STEPS 3

static void* filterEvenFoos(void)
{
    printf("42\n");
    return NULL;
}

static void* timesFooByTwo(int val)
{
    printf("%d\n", (val * 2));
    return NULL;
}

static void* mapFooToBar(double obj1, size_t obj2)
{
    printf("foo(%f)->bar(%zu)\n", obj1, obj2);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    void* (*functionSteps[NUM_STEPS])();
    functionSteps[0] = (void*)filterEvenFoos;
    functionSteps[1] = (void*)timesFooByTwo;
    functionSteps[2] = (void*)mapFooToBar;

    functionSteps[0]();
    functionSteps[1](42);
    functionSteps[2](3.14, &main);
    return 0;
}
```

You could port it to C++ in many ways, but you could use the [`va_arg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_arg/) functionality to get variable inputs like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <vector>

static void* filterEvenFoos(int na, ...)
{
    std::cout << 42 << std::endl;
    return NULL;
}

static void* timesFooByTwo(int na, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, na);
    std::cout << ((va_arg(vl, int)) * 2) << std::endl;
    va_end(vl);
    return NULL;
}

static void* mapFooToBar(int na, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, na);
    double obj1 = va_arg(vl, double);
    size_t obj2 = va_arg(vl, size_t);
    std::cout << "foo(" << obj1 << ")->bar(" << obj2 << ")" << std::endl;
    va_end(vl);
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<void* (*)(int, ...)> functionSteps;
    functionSteps.push_back(&filterEvenFoos);
    functionSteps.push_back(&timesFooByTwo);
    functionSteps.push_back(&mapFooToBar);

    functionSteps[0](0);
    functionSteps[1](0, 42);
    functionSteps[2](0, 3.14, &main);
    return 0;
}
```

You might note that the function signature changes slightly to allow a portable way to access the variadic arguments in each function.

If you're using C++11, you could also make use of the [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) inside the [`vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), but you still need to have matching function signatures.

You could also make use of classes and inheritance, or template specializations, but those could be extreme over-kill in your scenario.

In the end, it's not a direct port from the C code to C++, but it is doable.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this not possible in CPP?

```
functionSteps[0] = (void*) filterEvenFoos;
```

No, it is not.

It is not really valid C either.

#### Regarding Function To Pointer Conversion

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Function_to_pointer_conversion:

> Any function designator expression, when used in any context other than
>
> - as the operand of the address-of operator
> - as the operand of sizeof
>
> undergoes a conversion to the non-lvalue pointer to the function designated by the expression.

It does not say anything about converting a `void*` to a function pointer.

#### Regarding Conversions From `void*`

You can convert a `void*` to an object pointer.

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Pointer_conversions:

> A pointer to void can be implicitly converted to and from any pointer to object type with the following semantics:
>
> - If a pointer to object is converted to a pointer to void and back, its value compares equal to the original pointer.
> - No other guarantees are offered

Please note even in that section, there is no mention of converting a `void*` to a function pointer.

It's not clear to me why your computer does not report it as an error.

You can use

```
functionSteps[0] = filterEvenFoos;
```

if `filterEvenFoos` is of the right type of function. If the declaration of `filterEvenFoos` does not exactly match the expected type, i.e. a function that takes no arguments and returns a `void*`, then you can't use that either.

Comment: It  isn't valid in C either

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but the syntax is a bit dicey to get right.  It's easier if you use a typedef for your callback-function-type, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* filterEvenFoos() {return NULL;}
void* timesFooByTwo() {return NULL;}
void* mapFooToBar() {return NULL;}

typedef void* (*VoidFunction)();

int main(int, char **)
{
   const int numSteps = 3;

   VoidFunction functionSteps[numSteps];
   functionSteps[0] = filterEvenFoos;
   functionSteps[1] = timesFooByTwo;
   functionSteps[2] = mapFooToBar;
}
```